# From where I get all publish artifact of all stages of azure build pipeline instead of searching from all stages

Tags: azure-devops

I am publishing build artifact of each run over azure pipeline, whatever artifact I have published than can be accessible to that specific stage(run), But my query is in Azure is there any build artifacts repository where we can get all the build artifacts for all the builds of that pipeline ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all the build artifacts for all pipeline runs, you need to combine the following two Rest APIs： [Builds - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) and [Artifacts - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/artifacts/list?view=azure-devops-rest-4.1)

Here is a PowerShell example:

```
$token = "PAT"

$url="https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?api-version=6.0"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get -ContentType application/json

ForEach( $buildid in $response.value.id ) 

{

  echo $buildid

  $url1= "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/$($buildid)/artifacts?api-version=4.1"

  $response1 = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url1 -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get -ContentType application/json

  echo $response1 | ConvertTo-Json

}
```

This sample will traverse all pipeline runs and get relevant artifacts information.

**Update:**

When you use Classic Pipeline, you could add a PowerShell task and input the  PowerShell Script. Please change the parameters in the script to make it suitable for your organization

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response. As I am new with Pipeline configuration so I am not getting how I add this script using Classing Editor and even after execution of script where I can find all publish artifacts in Azure Devops ?

Comment: What is Classing Editor? You could get all publish artifacts from the output of the script.

Comment: Sorry. Its Classic Editor. Instead of yaml I am using Classic Editor.

Comment: @Milan Do you mean Classic Pipeline? If yes, please refer to my update.

Comment: Great its working fine. But only question is json result is available in pipeline log. Is it possible to show it in azure devops ? So non-technical user can download artifacts from there.

Comment: In all stages we have "Test" tab, similar separate tab will be fine to show all links available in json output of Powershell script.

Comment: Based on your experience if you have some other way to show all links in json then please suggest me.